# How to get a set of unique parents given a list of children in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table containing heirarchical data:

```
ID  Name      ParentID
--- --------- ---------
1   Alpha     2
2   Beta      3
3   Gamma     NULL
4   Delta     2
5   Epsilon   6
6   Zeta      NULL
7   Eta       1
8   Theta     NULL
```

Given a list of IDs, how do I get a list of all the unique root parent IDs?  I do not want the intermediate parents.

For example, let's say the list of IDs I am given is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.
The result I am looking for is:

```
ID
---
3
6
```

Clearly this calls for some kind of recursive query.  I think it might be possible to achieve using common table expressions (CTEs), but I am really having trouble wrapping my head around how it might be done.  All the examples I have seen so far seem to aggregate all the children and parents together to produce a complete list of the heirarchy, which isn't what I'm looking for.  Are there any SQL gurus out there that can give me a nudge in the right direction?  I do realize I can do this iteratively with multiple queries to the database but I am hoping not to have to resort to that.

I should note that I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Similar to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940489/find-contact-in-location-tree/14941396#14941396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example. The CTE recurses from child to parent.

```
; with  Cte as
        (
        select  ID
        ,       ParentID
        from    Table1
        where   ID in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        union all
        select  parent.ID
        ,       parent.ParentID
        from    Table1 parent
        join    Cte child
        on      child.ParentID = parent.ID
        )
select  distinct ID
from    Cte
where   ParentID is null
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c64f/3/0)

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
HAVING(count(ParentID)) < 2
```

at the end of your query.  use group by appropriately.